# Evaluate the following limit for the vector function when $t\to \pi/2$

Tags: limits

$$F(t) = ( \cos(2t), -4\sin(t), 2t/\pi )$$

I have completed this question by direct substituting the given limit for every $t$ in the $\hat{i}, \hat{j}$ and $\hat{k}$ vector positions. However, I am not sure if this is a viable method for this problem or if the answer I have gotten $(-1,-4, 1)$ is correct.

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for the feedback and the assistance with formatting my question.  This is actually my first time using stackexcange and really appreciate the help.